# How To Solve WP-DBManager Permission issue?

Tags: centos, nginx, permissions, wordpress, php-fpm

I've installed WordPress on a LEMP stack which is powered by CentOS 6.4. I installed WP-DBManager plugin today and it's showing an error which is mentioned below:

```
Your backup folder MIGHT be visible to the public

To correct this issue, move the .htaccess file from wp-content/plugins/wp-dbmanager to /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/backup-db
```

But guys how can I do this as Nginx does not support .htaccess file. Please tell me what permission should I give to backup-db folder that is located in wp-content folder.

The .htaccess file in the folder contains the following code:

```
<Files ~ ".*\..*">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

At this time when I directly open that "backup-db" folder, ngnix shows a **403 Forbidden** error. But the backups can easily be downloaded if someone has direct URL to the backup zip file located in that folder.

Please help me!

Comment: What is in this .htaccess file?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've added the .htaccess code. Please check and let me know what to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That .htaccess just denies all requests. You can easily do the same in nginx with a second `location`. For instance this will [`deny`](http://nginx.org/r/deny) every request in that directory:

```
location /wp-content/backup-db {
    deny all;
}
```